# Using dplyr to replace blanks with -1

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace `""` with `-1` in the entire dataframe.

This code gets executed without any errors, but its not making any changes. Can you please help?

```
df.Sample <- mutate(replace(df.Sample, c(1:13)=="", -1))
```

Comment: share a sample of your data

Comment: `df.Sample[ df.Sample == "" ] <- -1`

Answer (score 3):

If the `replace`ment is for all the columns, use `mutate_each`

```
library(dplyr)
df.Sample %>%
         mutate_each(funs(replace(., .=='', -1)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df.Sample <-  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5, ""), 4*5, 
             replace=TRUE), ncol=4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure whether the `""` are empty, factor, or else.
So I reommend just for being on the safe side convert the dataframe to one that strings are not treated as factors:

```
df.Sample <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5, ""), 10*13, replace=TRUE), 
                               ncol=13),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

then you can replace the values equal to `""` to be modified to -1.
so if among the columns 1 to 13 you want to do that:

```
for(i in names(df.Sample)){
    df.Sample[eval(parse(text=paste("df.Sample$",i))) == "",i] <- "-1"
}
```

You can later change the type to `as.numeric` if you want.